# Aiml 1.0 - * pattern

Tags: xml, bots, chatbot, aiml

I was wondering how can I create the AIML that matches this conversation:

```
User: What's my name?
Bot:  Right now I don't know. Tell me, what's your name?
User: Gandalf.
Bot:  Hello Gandalf.
```

So I tried to use this two categories.

```
<category>
    <pattern>WHAT'S MY NAME?</pattern>
    <template>
        <condition name="name_set" value="S"> <get name="name"/></condition>
        <condition name="name_set" value="">Right now I don't know.Tell me, what's your name?</condition>
    </template>
</category>
<category>
    <pattern>*</pattern>
    <that>Right now I don't know.Tell me, what's your name?</that>
    <template><think><set name="name"><star/></set><set name="name_set">S</set></think>Hello <srai>WHAT'S MY NAME?</srai>.</template>
</category>
```

But instead of choosing this last defined pattern, my bot is constantly answering the default answer, setted in another category using the * pattern but no **that** tag. What I'm doing wrong?

*Bonus question*: Probably you've noticed that I'm using a name_set global variable to see if I stored the name of the user: **empty** means NO, **S** means YES. I'm using this *escamotage* because in Program-O bot the AIML validator hasn't allowed me to use the **exists** attribute. If anyone know something more to fix the problem or has got any suggestion to give, please be my guest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the `<that>` in the category is incorrect. If I'm correct that refers to the final sentence of your bot's output. Then this would probably work better for you.

```
<category>
    <pattern>*</pattern>
    <that>Tell me *</that>
    <template>
      <think>
       <set name="name"><star/></set>
       <set name="name_set">S</set>
      </think>
      Hello <srai>WHAT'S MY NAME?</srai>.
    </template>
</category>
```

Comment: [SOLVED] I solved using your trick but ina  different way.
The <that> tag is equal to

* Tell me *

Thank you.